# Getting error 'value of type dict not supported' when calling an Oracle Stored Procedure in Python

Tags: python, oracle, python-2.7, cx-oracle

When calling an Oracle Stored Procedure using cx_oracle, I getting the following error Python value of type dict not supported.

My code is as follows -

```py
try:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.callproc("my_proc", [fname, hash, json])
    cursor.close()
    connection.commit()
finally:
    connection.close()
```

In my stored procedure I am passing in two strings (varchar2 in Oracle) and json data which in Oracle in a Clob.

Please note I am new to Python and still getting to grips with it.

Comment: What is the JSON value you are using? If it is a dict you'll need to use json.dumps() or something equivalent to convert it to a string first!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
try:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.callproc("my_proc", json.dumps([fname, hash, json]))
    cursor.close()
    connection.commit()
finally:
    connection.close()
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to work for me.  If you update your question with more detail we might be able to spot your issue

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("""
               create or replace procedure my_proc (
                   p1 in varchar2,
                   p2 in varchar2,
                   p3 in clob,
                   p4 out varchar2
               ) as
               begin
                 p4 := p1 || p2 || p3;
               end;
               """)

hash = "abc"
fname = "def"
json = "ghi"
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    myout = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.STRING)
    cursor.callproc("my_proc", [fname, hash, json, myout])
    print(myout.getvalue())
```

Output is:

```
defabcghi
```